# How to flatten values in a row in Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, flatten

guys

I've a problem with my data in big query. I have a dataset like pic #1 and I need to rank my users and group their ranking notes in a unique row (like pic #2). To be clear, my `ranking` column type is `int`, not an `array`.

Is it possible to handle this w/bigquery or do I need to transport this dataset to python and do this transformation there ?

**PIC #1 ORIGINAL DATASET**

[image: PIC #1 - ORIGINAL DATASET]

**PIC #2 GROUPED AND FORMATED DATASET**

[image: PIC #2 - GROUPED AND FORMATED DATASET]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' user, 10 ranking UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b',  2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 14 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', 21 
)
SELECT 
  user, 
  MAX(ranking) AS ranking_max,
  STRING_AGG(CAST(ranking AS STRING)) ranking_list
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY user
```

with result

```
Row user    ranking_max ranking_list     
1   a       14          10,12,14     
2   b       2           2    
3   c       22          22   
4   d       21          21
```

Note: if you need `ranking_list` to be ordered - you can use `ORDER BY` in `STRING_AGG` as in below

```
STRING_AGG(CAST(ranking AS STRING) ORDER BY ranking) ranking_list
```